# wandb — ImportError

Tags: python, importerror

I've successfully installed wandb on a Linux system, however, I run into an error when I try importing it.

```
>>> import wandb
[...]
ImportError: [PATH]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4absl12lts_2023012512log_internal9kCharNullE
```

I've tried reinstalling the package, but it still fails to import.

Comment: Please include the Linux distro and version along with the steps you installed `wandb`. Thanks!

Comment: Just tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6.9 using `venv`. It worked! Commands: `python3 -m venv .venv`, `. .venv/bin/activate`, `pip install wandb`, and then `python -c "import wandb; print(wandb.__version__)"` which returned **0.13.10** output.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue with Python 3.8.10 and 3.9 on CentOS Linux 7, installing `wandb` using pip.